# ArcGIS REST query result order is random

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-rest-api, map-service

What I try to do a identify operation on a polygon dataset in a ArcGIS REST MapService. For obscure reasons I can't change, the order of the results is important. To achieve this, the data is written in a specific order.

I am very sure this was working for quite a while but for reasons still unknown to me, the results are now presented in what seems to be a random order.

As this issue really bothers me I've spend quite some time to fix it, but with no results. It really puzzles me why and hopefully somebody here can point me in a right direction. Or point out that what I try is impossible.

I have a TEST environment where this still works, but as always TEST and PROD are not 100% equally configured. I am not the only one working in this environments, so it is possible someone changed something I do not know of.

What I have:

- Polygons in a feature class in an Azure geodatabase, chronologically written so the newest date has the lowest OBJECTID.
- Federated service published using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.6 to Portal for ArcGIS / ArcGIS for server 10.91.

What I tried:

- Recreated the feature class in the database from scratch.
- Overwritten the service with the new datasource from the existing ArcGIS Pro project.
- Republished to a new service with the new datasource from a new ArcGIS Pro project.

How do I reproduce this:
Go to the rest endpoint of the service (.../MapServer/50/query) and enter Where 1 = 1, Out Fields = DateString, Return Geometry = False. This returns the records in the order I prefer. The moment I add Input Geometry = point(106662,455150) the results are shuffled.

Comment: At least some ESRI services support `orderBy` https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/query-feature-service-layer-.htm.

Comment: You can't control display order without an ORDER BY clause (and incurring the cost thereof). Generating data with a reverse order on ObjectID isn't going to change the order in the spatial index, and that's what should be driving this query.

Comment: Thanks @user30184! Yes I am aware. But the application which uses the webservice does not support this parameter, so it really has to, just, work :s

Comment: If you absolutely need the results sorted, you'll need to write your own sorter. A Java servlet as a query proxy could accomplish this in no more than 60 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks @Vince! That makes sense, and might be the reason it used to work with less records in the featureclass.

Comment: `orderbyFields` has been part of the [Query (Map Service/Layer) - ArcGIS REST APIs | ArcGIS Developers](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/query-map-service-layer-.htm) since ArcGIS 10.4, I don't understand why you can't use it here.

Comment: @bixb0012 because the webgis viewer, geocortex essentials, does not seem to support this parameter,

Comment: I would make a feature request for adding the support into geocortex essentials.